# convexity of two linear spaces connected by a convex equality constraint

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If there are two sets of linear constraints in different variables, **Ax <= b** with **x_l <= x <= x_u** and **Cy <= d** with **y_l <= y <= y_u**, and a set of equality constraints of a specific non-linear but convex form relating the two sets of variables **e^y - x = 0**, is the feasible space convex, and what is the proof behind the answer? The difficulty seems to me that the equality constraint would be equivalently formulated as **e^y - x <= 0** and **e^y - x >= 0**, which means that one of these inequalities would be convex and the other would be concave, which may somehow create concavities in the feasible space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. All equality constraints has to be linear -- this is almost your observation.

As an example, take $-1 \le x \le 1$, $-1 \le y \le 1$ and $\exp(y) = x$. Then, the feasible set is a non-convex part of the graph of $\exp$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does that example still work if x is restricted to be non-negative?

Comment: Yes. Note that $x$ is always non-negative if $x = \exp(y)$.